# $P(A\cup B) = P(A\cap B) / P(B)$. Why doesn't the $P(B)$ cancel out?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

"This season, the probability that the Yankees will win a game is $0.49$ and the probability that the Yankees will score 5 or more runs in a game is $0.62$. The probability that the Yankees win and score 5 or more runs is $0.42$."

Shouldn't the probability be $0.49*0.62=0.30$?  How can they say that the answer is .42?

Also, shouldn't the $P(B)$ cancel out with the numerator in the above theorem.

Comment: The formula you are implicitly trying to use requires that the events $A,B$ are independent. In this case, they aren't.

Comment: This was a question that was given to me.  How should We be able to say that "The Probability that the   yankees win and score 5 or more runs is 0.42?"

Comment: @legionwhale, does this mean that I can't use the  formula for this problem??

Comment: What exactly is the problem asking you to evaluate? There is not a single question in what you have quoted. Just some assumptions. Post the exact problem.

Comment: This season, the probability that the Yankees will win a game is 0.49 and the probability that the Yankees will score 5 or more runs in a game is 0.62. The probability that the Yankees win and score 5 or more runs is 0.42. What is the probability that the Yankees would score 5 or more runs when they win the game? Round your answer to the nearest thousandth.  I know how to do the problem.  I am merely just confused why P(A and B) / P(B) = P(A|B), and no just P(A)

Comment: $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$ holds only if $A$ and $B$ are independent. Only then , $P(B)$ cancels out and you just get $P(A)$

Comment: Can you please give  an example of why/when P(A and B) might not always equal P(A)  * P(B)?

Comment: @Kyotiq Take a single fair coin, what is $P(\text{heads and tails})$? What is $P(\text{heads})P(\text{tails})$?

Comment: I think your title is supposed to be $P(A|B)=...$, not $P(A\cup B)=...$

Answer (score 4):

Multiplying the two probabilities only works if the two events are independent of one another. For example, the odds that two dice rolled separately will both be 6 is $\frac{1}{6}*\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{36}$. The two events in your problem are not independent. A team is significantly more likely to win if they have scored 5 or more runs. This is similar to calculating the probability that a die will roll an even number above three. The probability of rolling an even number is $\frac{1}{2}$, and the probability of rolling a number above 3 is also $\frac{1}{2}$. But this doesn't mean that the odds of rolling an even number above three is $\frac{1}{4}$. We can count the cases and see the the probability is $\frac{2}{6}$ or $\frac{1}{3}$. The discrepancy between the $0.30$ that you calculated and the $0.42$ that is cited in the problem represents the effect that score lots of runs has on the probability of winning a game.